# Pymongo aggregation remove array field

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have an object like this:

```
{
  '_id': 123,
  'myArray': [
    {'name': 'AAA', 'age': 32, 'nestedArray': [{'field1': 'oreos', 'field2': 'smarties'}]}, 
    {'name': 'BBB', 'age': 23, 'nestedArray': [{'field1': 'mars', 'field2': 'twix'}, {'field1': 'twirl', 'field2': 'aereos'}]}
  ]
}
```

I currently use two separate queries to remove the field I need:

```
query_myArray = { '_id': _id }
delete_myArray_element = {
        '$pull': {
            'myArray' : {'name': myArray_name},
        }
    }
self.collection.updateOne(query_myArray,delete_myArray_element)
```

and

```
query_nestedArray = {
        'myArray':
            { '$elemMatch': {
                'name': myArray_name,
                'nestedArray.field1': match_field1,
                }
            }
        }

    update_nestedArray = {
        '$pull': {
            'myArray.$[].nestedArray': {'field1': match_field1} 
        }
    }
    self.collection.update_one(query_nestedArray, update_nestedArray)
```

I would like to do this all in one query for efficiency reasons. I am trying to use `$unset` after matching the object on `_id`, but I do not know how to match on the array fields - I only want to remove a single field item and not the whole array.

Comment: don't think it's possible to do two update operations on the same array field. however you could do a [bulkwrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/index.html) to combine the two ops.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [Đĵ ΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4368485/%c4%90%c4%b5-%ce%9d%ce%b9%ce%93%ce%9e%ce%97%ce%9b%cf%88%ce%9a), ended up doing everythig as a bulkwrite query.